# Why we use @RequestHeader annotation while developing a REST API?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-rest

I am working on a limit login functionality for the authentication of the user. Well i have a single page application and that SPA hitting a REST API developed by using Spring Boot. In the API it is using a @RequestHeader annotation.

I want to understand why we need to use @RequestHeader annotation as well as the real use cases of using it  and what are the best practices we need to follow to use it?

## API CODE

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/first-time/user")
    public UserLoggedInInformation firstTimeAuthenticate(@Valid @NotNull
                                        @RequestBody UserPasswordData userPasswordData,
                                                         @RequestHeader(value    = "x-client-id",required = false) String xClientId,
                                                         @RequestHeader(value    = "x-b2b-domain",required = false) String domain) {

        log.debug("Rest Request to check first time user : {} from Application: {} and Domain: {}",userPasswordData,xClientId,domain);

       return authenticationOperations.authenticateFirstTime(xClientId,domain,userPasswordData.getUsername(),userPasswordData.getPassword());
        
    }
```

Comment: You need to use @RequestHeader when you want to access HTTP Headers in a Spring Rest Controller.

Comment: Why we need to access HTTP Headers and where and how we should use HTTP Headers if we access it? Please give me complete clarity on this and if possible share me a link so that i can get complete clarity on this.

Answer (score 1):

A better question would be "When" to use @RequestHeader while developing REST APIs (when we can easily send data using either @RequestBody or @RequestParam)

Nonetheless, whenever a piece of information is required by your whole application and it doesn't change as the business context changes throughout its lifecycle, then it's a good candidate for @RequestHeader.

However, if your info is needed in a very localized context or has limited usage then you should follow the general way of requesting it via @RequestBody or @RequestParam route.

In short, a piece of data that is consistent and is required globally throughout the application can be (should be) accessed via @RequestHeader.

In your example itself, the one-time usable password is being accessed via @RequestBody; however, xClientId is accessed using @RequestHeader.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @RequestHeader when you want to access HTTP Headers in a Spring Rest Controller.
HTTP headers purpose is to send meta data information to the server (and also in the response to the client) in addition to the actual logic information that is sent in the HTTP body.
You can see its purposes in: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

You can learn about http header using spring rest controller here:
[spring rest controller http header](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers)